# RxDB "Cannot open database state with newer RxDB version" error when trying to update from v13 to v15

Tags: rxdb

I'm trying to update my RxDB database from version 13 to version 15, but I'm encountering a very strange error:

```
bootstrap.tsx:242 RxError (DM5): RxError (DM5):
Cannot open database state with newer RxDB version. You have to migrate your database state first. See https://rxdb.info/migration-storage.html
Given parameters: {
args:{
"database": "dbname",
"databaseStateVersion": null,
"codeVersion": "15.10.0"
}}
```

Does this mean that there were changes in version 15 that require us to create a new database with a new name during migration?

If affirmative, it raises concerns. What would be the appropriate approach for updating and safeguarding data from prior versions such as 12/13 to version 15?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same scenario, I went into my database and dropped the collection called "_rxdb_internal" and it worked for me.
[image]

Just to be clear I am using it on server side and saving into a mongo database, so i removed this collection and it worked fine for me, I did not have to migrate the data or anything.